# Multiple choice filter input filed to filter on multiple choice sharepoint lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Recently I faced an issue I cannot solve myself  - hope some of you will be able to point me the direction or even maybe a solution :) ‌‌

I'm creating the canvas application to register the projects. One of the part of registration is choice of the project coach (Input_Project Coach) which should be drop down list with filter based on 3 inputs (2 of which are based on other input fields):

1. If the coach is avalible (**Open_Calc**); yes/no field on sharepoint list
2. Type of the project (**Input_ProjectType**); single choice dropdown
3. Location of the project (**Input_Factories**); multiple choice dropdown list

Currently I managed to filter it only on two first inputs:

```
Filter('eProject - Coach',
    Open_Calc="Yes",
    Input_ProjectType.Selected.Project_Type_Name in Concat(Coach_ProjectType.Value,Value,", ")
).Coach_Name_String
```

The 'eProject - Coach' is a sharepoint list name, and it contains these relevant columns to filter on:

- **Open_Calc**; calculated column that is changing the yes/no column to string
- **Coach_ProjectType**; multiple choice lookup column from another SP list
- **Coach_Factory**; multiple choice lookup column from another SP list

Do you know how can I filter that sharepoint multiple choice column (**Coach_Factory**) based on input in powerapps multiple choice drop-down list (**Input_Factories**)?

We can assume that (**Coach_Factory**) sharepoint lookup column contain for a single coach values like: RZS, FLCD, FDCL, FLCL etc., and the (**Input_Factories**) dropdown in app contain: FDCL, FCGWr, FRFWr -> and based on the apperance of FDCL in both (**Coach_Factory** column and **Input_Factories** field) that coach should be able to picked up from drop-down list (**Input_ProjectCoach**)

What I was trying to do more so far is:
Create the collection with all Factory names from **Input_Factories** (I manage to do that), and then:

```
Collection:
Clear(Choice_Factories);
ForAll(
    Input_Factories.SelectedItems,
    Collect(
        Choice_Factories,
        {
        FactoryName: ThisRecord.Factory_Name
        }
    )
);
```

**And then:**
Loop through that collection on-by-one and check if any of that factories are in concat(Coach_Factories ....) by using Filter() and then add that records to new collection:

```
Clear(Choice_Factories2);
    ForAll(
        With(
            {
                _Factory: Choice_Factories,
                _Coach: [@'eProject - Coach']
            },
            Filter(
                _Coach,
                _Factory.FactoryName in Concat(ThisRecord.Coach_Factory.Value,Value & "")
            )
        ),
        Collect(
            Choice_Factories2,
            ThisRecord.Coach_Name
        )
    )
```

But all of that with no luck :(

At the sentence '_Factory.Factory Name' I have information that i cannot act with tables here, but when i concat it to make text it don't loop by each separate factory but by all of them with the delimiter.

**1st:** PowerApps dropdown list with multiple selection of factories
[PowerApps View for Factory Choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hPpM.png)

**2nd:** Sharepoint list with coaches and multiple selection lookup column for factories
[Sharepoint list view with factories lookup column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKHQa.png)